# Can all Hypergraphs be Embedded in 3D Space?

Tags: graph-theory, hypergraphs

I once read that every graph there is could be embedded in 3D Space without edges crossing one another and that only *planar* graphs can be embedded in 2D such that their edges do not cross. I was thinking if there was a similiar thing for Hypergraphs. Something like "Every Hypergraph can be embbeded in [some space] such that no edges/hyperedges intersect. But only [some type] of Hypergraph can be embedded in 3D Space such that the edges/hyperedges do not intersect."

Does that [some type] exist? If it does, what are its features? What are the conditions a Hypergraph must fullfill so that it can be embedded in 3D space without edge/hyperedge intersection?

Comment: Consider the complete hypergraph on 5 points. In addition to five tetrahedral 4-faces, it has one 5-face. What would is even mean to embed this structure in 3-space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base problem is that the vertices in an edge of a hypergraph are not bounded for all hypergraphs. You can always take any cardinal $\mathfrak a$ (for example $\mathfrak a = \omega = \mathbb N_0 = \{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$) and look at the hypergraph with vertices $V=\mathfrak a$ and edgeset $E=\{\mathfrak a\}$ (i.e. the only edge present goes through all vertices). It cannot be embedded into any space $\mathbb R^\mathfrak b$ with $\mathfrak b < \mathfrak a$. As soon as $\mathfrak a$ gets infinite, you are also dealing with some slight problems about what the topology of $\mathbb R ^\mathfrak a$ (i.e. the set of functions from $\mathfrak a$ into $\mathbb R$) is even supposed to be.

**So there is no space in which *all* hypergraphs can be meaningfully embedded.**

However, on the other hand, if the number of vertices in your edges is limited, to say a finite $n\in\mathbb N$, and the number of vertices is at most the cardinality of the continuum, you should always be able to embed it into $\mathbb R^{n+1}$, for a reasonable definition of embedding. Enumerate your vertices to $\{v_i\}_{i\in I}$, and set the image of an edge $e=\{v_{i_1},\ldots, v_{i_m}\}$ with $m\leq n$ to be the convex hull of the set $\{(j,j^2,\ldots,j^n,j^{n+1}) : v_j\in e\}$. I think this would be an embedding without improper intersections.

For why, here is my approach: Imagine we have two edges $e$ and $f$ and want to see if they intersect. Let's set $p(j) := (j,j^2,\ldots,j^n,j^{n+1})$. assume that both contain $n$ vertices, $e=\{v_{i_1},\ldots, v_{i_n}\}$ and $f=\{w_{j_1},\ldots, w_{j_n}\}$. If their images intersect, there are two vectors $\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb R^{n+1}$ with $0\leq \lambda,\mu\leq 1$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \lambda_k = 1 = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \mu_k$ and $$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \lambda_k p(i_k) = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \mu_k p(j_k)$$
I believe based on this system of equations (remember that the images under $p$ are vectors) one can deduce that the intersection of the images of the edges can only be along the image of $e\cap f$ via some linear algebra, generalizing the proof for the case $n=2$.